# Retrieve selected value from picklist inside an html table using Salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I am trying to get the selected value of picklist. This picklist is inside a HTML table and the picklists are dynamically created.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.oppRecordTypeMappingList}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-label="" title="">{! item.Name}</td>
                        <td data-label="" title="">{! item.Source_Opp_Record_Type_Name__c}</td>
                        <td data-label="" title="">
                            <div class="slds-select_container"> 
                                <ui:inputSelect class="slds-select" aura:id="inputSelectRecType">
                                    <!-- <aura:iteration items="{!v.recordTypeList}" var="i" indexVar="index">
                                        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!i.Name}" label="{!i.Name}" value="{! i.Name == item.Renewal_Opp_Record_Type_Name__c}" />
                                    </aura:iteration> -->
                                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="ABC" label="XYZ" />
                                    <ui:inputSelectOption text="DEF" label="DEF" value="true" />
                                </ui:inputSelect>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
```

I get the picklist value if I hardcode the picklist options. But when options are populated using aura:iteration,

```
var elem = component.find('inputSelectRecType');
console.log(elem[0].get('v.value'));
```

returns undefined.

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to PREDEFINE the property that you are going to bind to.

```
<aura:attribute name="lead" type="Lead" 
              default="{ 'sobjectType':'Lead', 'LeadSource' : ''}" />
```

Make your input select:

```
<ui:inputSelect class="slds-select spear-select" aura:id="leadSource" value="{!v.lead.LeadSource}" 
                updateOn="change" label="Lead Source" labelClass="slds-form-element__label " 
                requiredIndicatorClass="slds-required" required="true" >
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.leadSourceValues}" var="source">
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!source.value}" label="{!source.label}" />
  </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

Then you can extract the value from lead attribute:

```
var lead = cmp.get("v.lead");
```

Comment: Thank you! This is it!  I am setting the value on ui:inputSelect from controller init method and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it partially! If I make change to picklist, then above code prints selected value. However if I don't change the selected value, it still prints undefined.

Is this an expected behavior?